# Add brackets to an array for google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

i posted this earlier but i don't think it was understood what i was asking. so here is an what i have a variable that contains:
`var locations = ['San Jose California', 37.279518, -121.867905], ['San Antonio Texas', 29.424122, -98.493629], ['Uvalde Texas', 29.209684, -99.786171]`

what i need is this format for google maps api:

```
var locations2 = [
      ['San Jose California', 37.279518, -121.867905],
      ['San Antonio Texas', 29.424122, -98.493629],
      ['Uvalde Texas', 29.209684, -99.786171]
];
```

i have tried this `var locations3 = "[" + locations + "]"` but i believe it makes it a string.

any ideas? thanks.

Comment: The posted code contains a syntax error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this with `array.push()` method like this:

```
var locations = [];
locations.push(['San Jose California', 37.279518, -121.867905], ['San Antonio Texas', 29.424122, -98.493629], ['Uvalde Texas', 29.209684, -99.786171]);
console.log(locations); //check the output
```

Comment: But I would like to push the variable so it would be something like location2.push(locations); if I push it into another array?

Comment: @DavidLopez you can push array to another array, for example `array.push(array2)`. So you can do like you suggested but remember to instantiate the array you want to include the other array, in your case it would be location2 array.